# wmd editor tabs not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, wmd-editor

Hello guys I'm trying to implement the wmd editor like this on stackoverflow but I can't show the buttons of the editor only the textarea appears.. here is my codes.. Am I doing something wrong here? Or missing something? Thanks hopefully you guys could help me.

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

```
<head>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/wmd.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/showdown.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/wmd.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

`<body>`
         `<div id="wmd-button-bar" class="wmd-panel"></div>`
      
       `<textarea id="wmd-input" class="wmd-panel"></textarea>`
      
       `<div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel"></div>`
      
       `<div id="wmd-output" class="wmd-panel"></div>`
`</head>`
    `</body>`